# Unable to locate or obtain driver for chrome

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, path, selenium-chromedriver

I am encountering an issue while setting the path for the chrome driver in my selenium project.
my chrome verson is 118.0.5993.89 and i have set the path but w sehile setting the path i didn't see any chromedriver.exe all i saw where a bunch of files and now i am getting this:

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
 line 51, in __init__
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  , line 44, in get_path
    raise NoSuchDriverException(f"Unable to locate or obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']}")
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to locate or obtain driver for chrome; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
```

I tried to set path for chromium driver but i am getting error in my console.